# How to Set the Conditional If Statement to ".offset().top" Equals to "Zero"?

Tags: jquery, html

*The question has gotten rewritten.*

## An Example:

Here is an example I have created:

**The Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/4hpC8/

## The jQuery:

```
/* First: */
/* Set the Position of the Division Tag to Fixed When Reaching the Top of the Window While Scrolling */

$(window).scroll(function(){
    /* var lasttop = 0; */    
    var u_div_cn = $('div#container_nav');

    var u_div_cn_os_top = $('div#container_nav').offset().top;


    if ( u_div_cn_os_top == 0 ) {      

        u_div_cn.addClass('set_position');

    };

});
```

## The CSS:

```
.set_position {    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

The above example does not work successfully and lets the `division tag` pass through.

## A Different Example for Comparison:

Here is a different example, in case somebody wants to compare:

**The Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/yr2B3/2/

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake! You should use this to get the value: `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: I have to state that I did build the above with trial and error. The method `.scrollTop()` is used in the above jQuery script. How can the `value` of that be `requested`?

Comment: Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/yr2B3/4/). I've added some code in `/* First: */`.

Comment: Use `if (u_os_top_read == 0)` not `if ($(u_os_top_read == 0))`.

Comment: I have edited the example in the addendum of the question.

Comment: But you want to know when we reached the top? If yes check my fiddle.